# how to give a number a leading zero in scheme

Tags: scheme

How do you give a number a leading zero in scheme language?
For instance, I want the time to give 09:05 AM with a leading zero in front of the 9 and 5, instead of having 9:5 AM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends heavily on what interpreter you're using. For example, in Racket this is how we do it:

```
(format "~a:~a AM"
        (~r 9 #:min-width 2 #:pad-string "0")
        (~r 5 #:min-width 2 #:pad-string "0"))

=> "09:05 AM"
```